# Аналоги шрифта Segoe Script Regular

Tags: шрифты, web-fonts

Ребят, может кто знает аналоги шрифта Segoe Script Regular? Поскольку он не работает в браузерах. В опере сработал, в хроме нет. На телефоном браузере - нет. В сафари - нет. Какой то он странный. Подскажите похожие шрифты пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего странного. Отображение шрифта зависит от наличия его в системе. Если шрифта нет, то браузер подбирает следующий из типов, указанных в css либо дефолтный установленный в браузере.

Если вам нужно отображать нестандартный шрифт на странице, то его надо подгружать вместе со страницей. Можно сконвертировать ttf шрифт в web-font с помощью онлайн-конвертеров. Только будьте осторожны с встраиванием проприетарных шрифтов на своем сайте. Данное семейство шрифтов принадлежит компании Microsoft и конвертация и встраивание шрифта будет приравнено к нарушению авторских прав.

Comment: https://fonts.google.com в помощь

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать правило `@import`. Вот так: 
`@import url(*ссылка на шрифт*)`

Comment: Нельзя, это так не работает.